# how to show image using Imageview parse in json

Tags: android, mysql, json

how to show image using json the script like this 
JSON:

```
{
   "wisata":[
      {
         "id":"2",
         "name":"labuan haji",
         "deskription":"terletak dikecamatan labuan haji tempat wisata ini sangat digemari oleh remaja lombok timur",
         "latitude":"223.00",
         "longitude":"24242.00",
         "image":"image/IMG_20130521_174542.jpg"
      }
   ]
}
```

displaying images with ImageView is parsed from json .. sorry my bad english

Comment: what image are you expecting ??

Comment: u need to append full path and add that image name above and idsplay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need full path to access the image file, you can append it to image after getting image from JSON like this `image="http://example.com/"+image;` then use below code to fetch bitmap image

```
URL url = new URL(image);//http://example.com/image/IMG_20130521_174542.jpg
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```